# dirname(__FILE__) on localhost

Tags: php, constants, wamp

I'm using WAMP and have a development site in the www directory. I want to use `dirname(__FILE__)` to define the path to the server root.

Currently I'm using a config file which contains:

```
define('PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

I'm including the config file in in my `header.php` file like this:

```
<?php require_once("config.php") ?>
```

Then, on my sub pages I use the constant `PATH` to define the path by including `header.php`.

```
<?php require_once("../inc/header.php"); ?>
```

However, my links are coming out like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\wamp\www/css/style.css" />
```

What do I need to do to fix this? And since I'm including my constant in the `header.php` file I don't have access to the constant in the initial `require_once("../inc/header.php");` What other method can I use to find the root for `header.php`?

Comment: Do you want to find the local path or the URL?

Comment: @deceze - both I guess. I'll need it to work once I push it to production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you just need to have

```
define('PATH', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

If you want to be super technical, you can do something like this instead.

```
define('PATH', str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
```

On a side note, **and more importantly**, you don't actually need them.  This will work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

When a href begins with a directory separator, it is considered relative to the document root, not the current working directory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been gone for a few days. Thanks for the  `href` tip. I put that in place and all is well there. However, I still need to use `define('PATH', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` to link up my `config.php` file. My `config.php` contains the constant to root. However, I need to defin the root before I call `header.php`. That's where I'm stuck. `index.php` works fine, because it's simply finds `config.php` and loads it. When I navigate to any other page, the link breaks. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure I'm getting what you mean.  Do you have a live link anywhere so I can see what the directory structure looks like?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I just figured out my mistake a few minutes ago. Take care.

Comment: @Paul No problem.  I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @Nilpo Well, would you please share that with the rest of us?

Answer (score 1):

`__FILE__` is a filesystem path, not an URL path. I think you may be getting confused about which you need. To include php files or move things around, youll want to use the filesystem path. To create URLs to resources youll want to use the URL.

For filesystem stuff you can use what the `dirname(__FILE__)`. So in your front controller or top level entry points if youre not using the front controller pattern you might have things like:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
define('INC_PATH', ROOT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes');
```

As far as asstes go (css, images, js) i like to keep these in a single location at the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`  so the path is always `/css/path/to/file.css` regardless of where you are in the file structure. This can be a problem if you develop in subfolders on your local machine or testing server, but its easily avoided by using Virtual Hosts so that every site has its own file structure completely separate form others.

Comment: But that doesn't give us portability.

Comment: Sure it does... you just make sure you always have the same relative installations and then you are fine. For example if the DOCROOT is `/PATH/TO/PROJECT/public` then in your FC you can do `define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$server = str_replace('\\','/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$server = (substr($server,-1)=='/'?substr($server,0,strlen($server)-1):$server);
!defined('PATH')?define('PATH', 'http://'.str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],$server , str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)))):'';
```