# WAMP showing absolute path when echoing dirname(__FILE__)

Tags: php, apache, path

I did this:

```
echo dirname(____FILE____)
```

and it keeps showing as full absolute path as

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/VertrigoServ/www/dir/file.php
```

Why is that? I expect it to show

```
dir/file.php
```

I am using WAMP which is Apache on Windows.

BTW, calling `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does the same thing - it shows full path.

Comment: PHP doc says: "*The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, __FILE__ always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances*". Why would you expect anything else than the file path?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain relative path of script in webroot?

Comment: yes the path relative to root.

Comment: Duplicate question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337731/dirname-file-on-localhost

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$webPath = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__));
```

It'll take the absolute path to the file and remove the document root portion of it which should leave you with the path and file absolute from the document root.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns a location with / and `__FILE__` returns it with \, thus nothing is replaced at all (tested under windows)

Comment: You could do `str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` on the doc root to counteract this issue on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't state, if you're using wordpress I solved this issue by using:

```
file(bloginfo('home_url').'<path-to-file-without-leading-slash>')
```