# Including files from different folders after changing the document root

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute-path, php-include

I am working on a project using WAMP. The `vhost` is configured like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName LearningPHP
   DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/learning_php/public/page/
   <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/learning_php/public/page/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require local
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Windows `host` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       LearningPHP       # Project wamp64/www/learning_php
::1             LearningPHP       # Project wamp64/www/learning_php
```

The project structure looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this:

- when I access the website to land on `learning_php/public/page/index.php` (I think I accomplished this through the `vhost` configuration);
- inside each folder under `page` directory (e.g. `login`, `profile_add` etc.) there are two files: `index.php` and `process.php`. I used this approach to organize my project better (I am not yet familiarized with the `MVC` pattern);
- inside the `css` and `js` folders the name of the files matches the name of the folder under the `page` directory (e.g. `page > profile_add` => `css/profile_add.css` or `js/profile_add.js`). Later on I will merge all `css` and `js` files a page needs into individual files to limit the HTTP requests;

The problem I am experiencing:

- I cannot figure out how to include the `css` and `js` files. I think this happens because I rewrite the `DocumentRoot` in the `vhost` configuration.

I tried answers from similar questions using `PHP` constants, but I could not figure out what the issue is. For instance, I tried to add this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css">` to the `index.php` under the `page` folder and it did not work. I also used the file location on disk, but no result.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting someone else on this issue I concluded (strictly referring to my own project) that:

- Having the structure displayed above the css file cannot be access by the browser because it is simply outside the `document root` specified in the `vhost` configuration. An alternative is to point the `document root` to `learning_php/public/` and structure the project this way:

[image]

- another way to accomplish the desired result, but without modifying the project structure, is to read the css files via PHP and then store/ output the content wherever needed.

**The bottom line** is that, as far as I could find out, folders outside the `document root` are not accessible to the browser (which makes sens keeping in mind the security reasons and how most of the PHP frameworks use this principle). However, the same file can be manipulated using `server-side` scripting.

Please correct me, if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found another solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823495/wamp-showing-absolute-path-when-echoing-dirname-file)

Code:

```
$includePath = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__));
```

WAMP Servers tends to put the document root, you can delete that with `str_replace();` so your final code should look like:

```
$includeReplace = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', str_replace('\\', '/', '../css/styles.css'));
```

then in html put:

```
<link href="<?php echo $includeReplace; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Had to fix the solution

Comment: i can see why your code did not work because you only went back one file instead of 2 to get to the public folder

Comment: Your public folder is 2 directories behind, `../public/css/styles.css` just add another `../` so `../../public/css/styles.css`

Comment: Okay, now `href="<?php echo $includeReplace; ?>"` returns `href="/index.php"`. I still think the `vhost` configuration causes this...

Comment: try just putting `<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />` in just plain text with out PHP.

Comment: I tried it and when I click `view-source` the link looks like this: `<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />` and when I click it it goes to `http://hrevaluation/css/style.css` with `404` code...

Comment: hmm i know why now

Comment: when you view the html/php file through the web browser it prevents looking for file in the root directory. Your domain is configured at the `page` folder. So if you add the js & css files to the page directory and put `<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />` Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

`$includePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '../css/styles.css';` then 
`include ''.$includePath.'';` then In html:
`<link href="<?php echo $includePath; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
I tend not to use `../../path/path/file.txt` and you only need to go back one file instead of two. Try using the function `dirname(__FILE__);` to get the current directory.

This is what i use, hope it helps.
Any problems try [Clicking Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: Can you please clarify the use of this line `include ''.$includePath.''`? It returns: `href="C:\wamp64\www\learning_php\public\page../css/styles.css">`. Thanks.

Comment: are you using a web server?

Comment: Usually when that happens is when the files are not running on a server.

Comment: I am using WAMP and Virtual Hosts. If I used this '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">' (which should work). When I go to view-source and click the `href` link it doesn't load the `css` file as it should, but rather it goes to `learningphp/public/css/style.css` and it throws page not found.

Comment: And are you using wordpress

Comment: No WordPress. I built the folder structure from scratch.

Comment: Okay posted a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the configuration to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName LearningPHP
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

if that does not work try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName LearningPHP
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/learning_php/public/page/
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then you can use:

`<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! Sorry I took me so long to reply, I went further on with investigating the problem. I will post what I found out in a separate answer in order to attach an image as well. Also, it was necessary to replace `stylesheets` with `stylesheet`.