# How to display image from local folder

Tags: php, image, directory

I made a form in which a user can upload images. I am storing the copy of the uploaded image into a folder named "pics"(full path is C:\wamp\www\pics). I am also storing the name of the image in my database table.

I want to display all images in a page. I created a script. Used while and foreach loop to fetch the name of the image and then added the name in the image tag. It's now displaying a blank broken box.

The address of the image is correct. I select "Copy image location" by right clicking on the pic and it's displaying the correct path. eg: C:\wamp\www\pics\abc.JPG

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    //Including SQL Connection Credentials
    require_once("sql_connection.php");

        $sql_fetch_pics = "SELECT name FROM pics";
        $query_fetch_pics = mysql_query($sql_fetch_pics);
        while($fetched_pic = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_fetch_pics)){
            foreach($fetched_pic as $display_pic){
                $full_img_name = dirname(__FILE__)."\pics\\".$display_pic;

                echo "<img src='".$full_img_name."'/>";
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? "a blank broken box" doesn't explain your  issue very well.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The src tag should be URL, not filesystem path:

```
$full_img_name = "/pics/".$display_pic;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
$full_img_name = "/pics/".$display_pic;
```

**Explanation goes here:** [dirname(__FILE__) on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337731/dirname-file-on-localhost/9337870#9337870)